# Converting XML to Object and Preserve HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, json, parsing

I have an XML File that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <name>Test</name>
        <changelog>
            <ul>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test 2</li>
                <li>Test 3</li>
            </ul>
        </changelog>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now what I want to do is convert this to a PHP Object while preserving the HTML. Here's how I'm reading the XML:

```
$simpleXML_plugin_objs  = simplexml_load_file( 'plugins.xml' );
$plugin_obj_arr         = json_decode( json_encode( $simpleXML_plugin_objs ) );
```

And get the following:

```
stdClass Object (
    [plugin] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [name] => Test
            [changelog] => stdClass Object (
                [ul] => stdClass Object (
                    [li] => Array (
                        [0] => Test
                        [1] => Test 2
                        [2] => Test 3
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried wrapped the HTML in `<![CDATA[ ]]>` but then I just receive an empty changelog Object. What can I do to preserve my HTML whenever parsing my XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option:

```
simplexml_load_file( 'plugins.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement' , LIBXML_NOCDATA );
```

`CDATA` sections are loaded even without this option:

```
$changelog = $simpleXML_plugin_objs->children()->children();
echo $changelog[1];
```

But they are not made into regular object variables, so `json_encode()`, `print_r()`, and other inspecting functions see them as empty `SimpleXMLElement` objects:

```
print_r($simpleXML_plugin_objs);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Could you edit and add more information on why I needed to add this extra information for future readers please?